# HLSL - Combining textures

Tags: c#, hlsl, xna-4.0

I'm trying to combine two textures in HLSL - specifically, I want to take the alpha values from a base image, and the color data from an overlay image.

My pixel shader for this looks like this:

```
float4 PixelShaderFunction(VertexOut input) : COLOR0
{
    float4 baseColor = tex2D( BaseSampler, input.baseCoords.xy ).rgba;
    float4 overlayColor = tex2D( OverlaySampler, input.overlayCoords.xy ).rgba;

    float4 color;
    color.r = overlayColor.r;
    color.g = overlayColor.g;
    color.b = overlayColor.b;
    color.a = baseColor.a;

    return color.rgba;
}
```

and my blend state looks like this:

```
    BlendState bs = new BlendState();
    bs.AlphaSourceBlend = Blend.SourceAlpha;
    bs.AlphaDestinationBlend = Blend.DestinationAlpha;
    bs.ColorSourceBlend = Blend.SourceColor;
    bs.ColorDestinationBlend = Blend.DestinationColor;
```

What this leaves me with is a washed out version of what should be the overlay color.
I've tried numerous permutations of the BlendState settings, and played with the pixel shader math quite a bit, but to no avail.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: you could make that hlsl function a little nicer. color = float4 ( baseColor.rgb, overlayColor.a);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how C# handles stuff, but in general, you'll want

```
AlphaSourceBlend = SrcAlpha
AlphaDestinationBlend = InvSrcAlpha
```

(C# calls it SourceAlpha and InvSourceAlpha, respectively). And, obviously, you'll want to enable alpha blending, but I'm sure you did that.

Comment: The trick, as it turns out, was setting BlendState to NonPremultiplied and wiping out the explicitly defined state I have above all together.  Wouldn't have tried that if I didn't go back to make really sure I had Alpha Blending enabled, so thanks :)